# Open source test management tool

Tags: linux, open-source, software-testing

I have been in search for a simple test management tool which is open source and runs on Linux environment which I want to host it locally.

The key features I am looking out for are as follows:

1. Requirements management (can be of technical, design, functional, non-functional)
2. Test Plan creation using the selected requirements
3. test cases update, which additionally should have a clear mapping from requirement to test plan to test cases (in order to maintain traceability)
4. keep a place for test execution, as we keep running it in sprints, the impact based regression is also planned and should be selected during the test plan phase

I have explored few options like [TestLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestLink), [Tarantula](http://www.testiatarantula.com/), [xQual](http://www.xqual.com/) etc, but still unsatisfied as they would need a huge set of configurations to be done and afraid of choosing them as it might not be best bet for an agile kind of environment.

I was pretty inline with the tool *Tarantula,* but unfortunately the support ended and the code pushed into git is currently running through a lot of errors and is taking up a huge time inorder to start using it.

So any good advice of tools around this kind of test management is welcome and I am open to try out various tools (but we are kind of looking for specific open source/free tools).

Comment: Try ZenTao and Restyaboard to your list. Both are open source and for agile teams.

Answer (score -1):

After reviewing recent open source tools, we've put a [blog post](https://blog.testlodge.com/free-test-case-management-tools-list/) together listing all the free test case management tools which are currently available.

The top tools which we found are:

- Tarantula - Open source tool that is suitable for agile testing.
- Testopia - An extension of Bugzilla, a traditionally bug tracking tool.
- qaManager - Another option which has options to track releases.
- TestLink - One of the most common tools which people often turn to.

If anyone finds any tools that we've missed, please do let me know.

Thanks
Scott

Comment: Thanks Scott , it’s definitely s good blog to get started